# Will a script tag appended to an element run before the next line after .append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fetching an HTML document from the server, storing it in a variable `data`, then appending it to a `<ul>` element on the page. Here is what `data` looks like:

```
<script>
    hasNext = true // global variable
</script>
<li class="result">one</li>
<li class="result">two</li>
```

Then in my main Javascript for the page, I do this:

```
ulElement.append(data);
if (hasNext) {
    ulElement.append(nextPageButton);
}
```

It seems to work, but I just wanted to make sure that the code in the `<script>` tag will always run before my `if` statement. And I couldn't find any info on this possible race condition online. Thoughts?

Comment: If that's *all* you want to do, certainly you could do it without injecting any scripts at all, which you should generally avoid

Comment: @Shikkediel My "main" javascript snippet is executed after doc ready, when the user presses a button on the page.

Comment: @Amit Any ideas? I thought about putting that `true` value inside an HTML comment and reading it that way, but it seemed pretty hacky to me.

Comment: i mean... you could always use an attribute. surely that'd be better than injecting a global variable.

Comment: But it'd likely be even better if your server told the client up front how many results there are, then you can handle "has next" purely clientside without the server having to tell you there's more data on each request.

Comment: put this in your string: `<!--hasNext-->` when you want to go inside the if, and change your if to: `if(data.indexOf('<!--hasNext-->') >= 0)`

Comment: Why not just return JSON from your server where you have two items in your JSON, a `hasNext` property and an `htmlString` property.  Then, no hacks involved at all.  You parse the JSON and read both properties and use them like normal Javascript would.

Comment: I like all these suggestions, but I ended up going with @KevinB 's suggestion. It was the easiest to implement and the "totalPages" value was already being passed into the templating engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independent of whether or not this is a good idea....

In order for the browser to interpret your dynamically inserted DOM, it has to parse the content you are providing. This is a synchronous process (assuming your JS doesn't do any AJAX requests, `setTimeouts` etc). From the [Google Dev blog](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript?hl=en):

> When the HTML parser encounters a script tag, it pauses its process of
>   constructing the DOM and yields control over to the JavaScript engine;
>   once the JavaScript engine has finished running, the browser then
>   picks up from where it left off and resumes the DOM construction.

This means that the browser is guaranteed to process and execute the JS in the script tag (as well as add the DOM in the string) before it moves onto the next JS command: `if (hasNext) {...`.

In your example it wouldn't matter where the `<script>` tag was in relation to the rest of the dynamically inserted DOM in `data` because there is no dependency between the DOM and that script. As long as it is in `data`, the browser will process those commands before proceeding to the line after `append`.  E.g. this would work just as well

```
<li class="result">one</li>
<li class="result">two</li>
<script>
    hasNext = true // global variable
</script>
```

Since your code is checking the dynamically 'injected' variable after the `append` call, the variable (`hasNext`) is guaranteed to exist (as long as it was in a `<script>` tag in `data`).

For example:

```
$( ".test" ).append( "<p>Test</p><script>var globalVariable = 123;" );
$( ".test" ).append( globalVariable );
```

will write:

```
<p>Test</p>123
```

---

The most likely race condition is from some server interaction not specifying the `hasNext` variable, in which case the code will either use the falsey value of that variable:

```
if (undefined) { 
    alert('I won\'t be called'); 
} else { 
    alert('I will be called'); 
}
```

-OR, the more risky version-

your `if (hasNext) { ... }` will use the previous value of that variable from a prior call to `append` with different `data`. This is quite risky and possibly the best reason for avoiding this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it this way, maybe you can wait for the page to have loaded by using window.onload.

```
ulElement.append(data);
$(function(){
    if (hasNext) {
        ulElement.append(nextPageButton);
    }
});
```